# Telegram-BOT userid is just a private chatid?

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm making a bot that receive direct messages and isn't in a chat room, the userid and chatid is the same.
If i put the bot in a room, the chatid will be the same for all but the userid will be different?
If the bot have to respond to a specific user i have to use the userid instead of the chatid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
I made the whole stuff to test it and:

- the chatid is the same as the userid when messaging directly with the bot
- the chatid is a negative long when the message is sent in a chat room
- the bot can't send private messages to someone (even if they are both in the same chatroom) if that user don't send first a message to the bot